# SQL WHERE clause same column multiple times?

Tags: sql, database

My table looks like this, let's call it Table1:

```
ID  | value  |  formID
----------------------
25   Business  1001
16   John      1001
5    2/20/17   1001
30   FormXYZ   1001
25   Nursing   2345
16   Sam       2345
5    1/15/17   2345
30   FormXYZ   2345
25   Tech      4500
16   Sam       4500
5    2/1/17    4500
30   FormC     4500
```

The **ID** is the unique identifier of that field:

25 = Department

16 = Name

5 = Date

30 = Form Name, we have multiple different Forms, and I just need FormXYZ data.

**FormID** is a unique ID for each form submitted, the form contains 3 fields.

I have been trying to write a single query that retrieves all data looking something like this if possible:

```
Department  | Name  | Date
Business      John    2/20/17
Nursing       Sam     1/15/17
```

Here is what I have been trying, nesting and CASE didn't seem to work right for me, so I am posting here and I am right back where I started at.

```
SELECT value
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = '25'
  UNION ALL
SELECT value
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = '16'
  UNION ALL
SELECT value
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = '5'
  UNION ALL
SELECT value
FROM Table1
WHERE ID = '30' and value = 'FormXYZ'
```

Comment: Your design is not relational, why do you expect to get your result with a "relational" tool such as SQL? Why don't you use the application language?

Comment: The table is how it is unfortunately - I cannot change it. I am simply trying to get a little more organized View since the application takes too long to look up entries and I would have to do a lookup for every single "ID" (and I have 12 in my real form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select dp.value as department,
       n.value as name,
       dt.value as date
from
    (select formID, value from table1 where id = 25) as dp
    inner join (select formID, value from table1 where id = 16) as n
               on dp.formID = n.formID
    inner join (select formID, value from table1 where id = 5) as dt
               on dp.formID = dt.formID
    inner join (select formID, value from table1 where id = 30) as f
               on dp.formID = f.formID
where f.value = 'FormXYZ';
```

OR

```
select
    case when id = 25 then value end as department,
    case when id = 5 then value end as date,
    case when id = 16 then value end as name
from table1
where formId in (select formID from table1
                 where id = 30 and value = 'FormXYZ')
      and id in (5,16,25);
```

Comment: I just tried the first example you gave with inner joins, it worked beautifully!!! You are a lifesaver.

Comment: I think the second is faster

Comment: I was just about to ask which one was faster, thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to transpose data in SQL is to use case statements and roll up the data using a group by:

```
select 
    formID,
    max(case when ID=25 then value else null end) as Department,
    max(case when ID=16 then value else null end) as Name,
    max(case when ID=5 then value else null end) as Date
from Table1
group by formID
```

This produces:

```
formid Department Name Date 
1001   Business   John 2/20/17 
2345   Nursing    Sam  1/15/17 
4500   Tech       Sam  2/1/17
```

You can add a where clause as needed.  This should get the data in a single scan.